# Can we use async on windows playbook for Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I read the [document](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html) regarding fire and forget task from Ansible.

But when tried to write a one to use on my windows playbook

```
- name: install dotnet4
  win_chocolatey: 
   name: dotnet4
   state: present
  async: 1000
  poll: 0
  register: dotnet_sleeper
```

my control machine shows

```
TASK [windows.async.test : install dotnet4] *********************************
fatal: [192.168.0.165]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The async task did not return valid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded"}
```

Does that mean the async module is not supported on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/287).

Take a look at the linked issue page for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks,  will look follow up from there.

Comment: This issue was closed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue [287](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/287) was closed and a similar issue [22575](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22575) was opened/fixed shortly thereafter.

Additionally, Ansible has posted an article detailing how to use [Asynchronous Actions and Polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_async.html).

I've confirmed the async exampled below works 2.4.2.0+

```
- name: CHECK IF IIS WEB SERVER IS INSTALLED
  async: 10
  poll: 0
  register: iis_install_result
  win_feature:
    name: Web-Server
    state: present

- name: CHECK ON IIS WEB SERVER INSTALL STATUS
  async_status: jid={{ iis_install_result.ansible_job_id }}
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 30
```